# Почему, когда я "сую" один тип данных, в данном случае значимый тип, в тип object, изменения в ней не влияют на переменную типа object

Tags: c#

Почему, когда я "сую" один тип данных, в данном случае значимый тип, в тип object, изменения в ней не влияют на переменную типа object

```
 int x = 10;

 object obj = x;

 x = 5;
 Console.WriteLine(obj); //вывод 10, а не 5
```

Если возможно, то могли бы объяснить, как можно проще. Заранее благодарен.

Comment: ммм, а что вы хотели то? конечно 10 тк. obj после переопредиления не переписали)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут всё оч. просто:

- Создаёте в стеке (*грубо*, [тут](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F) можете узнать доп. инфу) переменную `x`
- Упаковываете (boxing (не знаю точно как на русском)), т. е. *копируете* эту переменную в кучу (`obj`)
- Изменяете значение переменной в *стеке* (т. е. *не* изменяете значение переменной в *куче*)

Тут вы выделяете (или используете) память в 2-х местах, следовательно от изменение одного не будет меняться другое.

---

Если вам нужно изменение by-ref [по ссылке], то используйте… [`ref`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref#passing-an-argument-by-reference)!

Пример #1:

```cs
static void Main()
{
    var x = 0;

    SomeMethod(ref x); // by-ref

    Console.WriteLine(x); // 5
}
static void SomeMethod(ref int x) // by-ref
{
    x = 5;
}
```

Пример #2:

```cs
public struct SomeStruct // 16 byte size
{
    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }
}
public sealed class SomeClass
{
    SomeStruct @struct;

    public ref SomeStruct Struct => ref @struct; // by-ref (могут менять поля `@struct`)
}

static void Main()
{
    var @class = new SomeClass();

    @class.Struct.X = 7.0; // если by-val (т. е. без `ref` в `SomeClass.Struct`), то не работает, т.к. значение копируется
    @class.Struct.Y = -3.5; 

    Console.WriteLine(@class.Struct.X); // 7
    Console.WriteLine(@class.Struct.Y); // -3,5
}
```

Comment: примерчик бы по последнему совету

Comment: @aepot щас забацаем

Comment: Насчёт куча/стек это вроде не точно. А вот что при боксинге/анбоксинге образуется новый объект - это наверняка.

Comment: @CrazyElf я же сказал, что тут всё *грубо*. ясен-красен, что локальная переменная может храниться не только в стеке, иначе мы получаем хрень а не приложение, которое даже регистры не использует :)